# Python: Socket Programming: accept() and connect calls

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have been self-learning python since few months now , and finally learning Socket programming. As an text book exercise, I am supposed to design a half-duplex chat system . Below is the code. The first request and response are just fine , but everytime I try sending a second message from client, the server seems to be hanging. The program is TCP based.

I am suspecting that since ss.accept() is being called everytime a new message has to be sent, a new thread is being created but since I have made only 1 call to sc.connect() from client , may be my new connection at the server end is hanging there for infinite time.

As a trail : I called ss.accept() outside the while loop, ie making only 1 connection and listening to data over and over on while loop, the conversations works just fine

Can someone please have a look a the code and help me understand where exactly is the issue.

Since, I am learning, I have not moved to twisted yet. I want to learn all the basics first before I move to frameworks.

```
     !bin/usr/env python

import socket, sys
HOST =''
PORT = 1060
ADDR =(HOST,PORT)

def userinput(sock):
    usermessage = input('>')
    sock.sendall(str(len(usermessage)))
    return usermessage


def server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(ADDR)
    s.listen(1)
    print 'the server is listening at',s.getsockname()

    while True:
        ss,sockname = s.accept()    
    #listen to determine the bytes sent by client
        msglen = ss.recv(4096)
    #accept the complete message
        msg = ss.recv(int(msglen))
        print 'client:', repr(msg)
        servermsg = userinput(ss)
        ss.sendall(servermsg)
        print " ---------------"
    ss.close()

def client():
    sc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sc.connect(ADDR)    
    while True:
        message = userinput(sc)
        sc.sendall(message)
        replylen = sc.recv(4096)
        reply = sc.recv(int(replylen))
        print "reply:",reply

        print "----------------"
    sc.close()

if sys.argv[1:] == ['server']:
    server()

elif sys.argv[1:] == ['client']:
    client()
else:
    print >> sys.stderr,'usage:tcp_2_7.py server|client[host]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trial - accepting once and then receiving multiple messages - is how you should do this. Calling `accept` is waiting for a new connection - you don't need to do this every time you want to send or receive a message, just as you don't want to call `connect` every time you want to send or receive.

Think of it this way:

When you connect to a chat server, do you connect, send a message, then disconnect immediately? No - you have a constant open connection which messages are sent through, and the connection is only closed at the end of a chat session.

From the docs on [`accept`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> `socket.accept()`
>
> Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an
>   address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair
>   (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and
>   receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to
>   the socket on the other end of the connection.

Comment: @ Jozzas :Thanks for that quick explanation ! so incase I have multiple clients, thats when I will be calling the accept and connect in loop for each client ,server session.

Comment: @durga Yep! Absolutely. Libraries like twisted can make this much easier by managing the pool of connections, rather than you having to do it yourself. It's good to understand though.